# Sample data in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I need to get some sample data from HDFS.

I am using :

```
hadoop fs -tail dev/sample.csv
```

It displays last kilobyte of the file to stdout.

---

- Is there any way to use `hadoop fs -tail` via Java API?
- Is there any other way to get sample data (*random*) from HDFS?

Comment: what's the problem just using a reader?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some datasets in [aws repo](https://aws.amazon.com/es/datasets/?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1)

From `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.tail(String[], int)` you can use hdfs dfs -tail, for example:

```
long fileSize = srcFs.getFileStatus(path).getLen();
long offset = (fileSize > 1024) ? fileSize - 1024: 0;

while (true) {
  FSDataInputStream in = srcFs.open(path);
  in.seek(offset);
  IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 1024, false);
  offset = in.getPos();
  in.close();
  if (!foption) {
    break;
  }
  fileSize = srcFs.getFileStatus(path).getLen();
  offset = (fileSize > offset) ? offset: fileSize;
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    break;
  }
}
```